# Python : removing "\n" from a file name

Tags: python

Here I am creating a program to create a file named current directory+url+system date and time .txt
On using netloc to extract only flipkart from http://www.flipkart.com file created contains \n. How to remove \n from the file.

```
class FileHandler(object):

    def create_file(self,url):
        print 'creating file....'
        flipkart = urlparse(url)
        filename = flipkart.netloc



        #filename = dns.name.from_text(url).split(3)[1].to_text(omit_final_dot=True)
        #filename = dns.name.from_text(url).split('www.')[1].to_text(omit_final_dot=True)
        #str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
        print 'file is---'
        print filename
        #filename = url
        dir = os.getcwd()

        #print 'Current directory path is-'
        #print dirPath


        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        now = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M")
        dirPath = os.path.join(dir,filename)
        dirPath.replace("\n","-")
        #filenameCreated = dirPath + now
        filenameCreated = dirPath + now
        #filenameCreated = filenameCreated1.splitlines()
        print filenameCreated
        f = self.openfile(filenameCreated + '.txt', 'a')
        #readFile(f)
        return f
        #self.writeFile(f)



#defining openfunction
    def openfile(self,filename,mode):
        try:
            open(filename,mode)

        except Exception, err:
            print("File cannot be opened.")
            print(str(err))
        return
```

Comment: What is the output of your program.

Answer (score 2):

You can append .rstrip('\n') to a string to remove newline characters.

So you can try something like:

```
filename = filename.rstrip('\n')
```